# How to activate 'Pan' with right mouse button [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, mouse, pan, ginput

I am building an application in matlab that digitizes an image. I am using ginput() in order to do that. I am wondering if there is any way I can use the right mouse button (button 3) or the scroll wheel (button 2) to PAN? When I click and hold the button I want to activate pan. When I pull my finger off the button I want it to return to ginput().

Answer (score 0):

Play with the `windowbuttondownfcn`, `windowbuttonmotionfcn`, and `windowbuttonupfcn` properties of your figure handle (see [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#zmw57dd0e274973)).

for example, this causes the figure window to return '1' when you 'right' click on it, and return 0 otherwise:

```
set(gcf, 'windowbuttondownfcn', @(x,y) display(y==3))
```